# Is there any real world example of nested mappings of solidity?

Tags: javascript, blockchain, solidity

Is there any real world example of nested mappings of solidity?
The previous day I was working with mapping functions and I found literally many real world applications for simple mapping but not for nested mappings. Please help
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nn825.png)

Answer (score 4):

A very common case is the approval mechanism on [ERC-20](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-20) and other token standards.

```
mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) approvals;
```

This structure is used to keep track of token approvals. Example: "Alice *(1st address)* approves Bob *(2nd address)* to spend 100 *(uint)* of her tokens".

A more common case than "approvals between people" is usually an approval from a person to a DApp. For example: "Alice approves Uniswap to pull 100 USDT from her wallet." And Uniswap is programed to take her USDT only at the moment when she's buying some other tokens against USDT.

It's also used for the same reason in the OpenZeppelin ERC20 [implementation](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v4.5.0/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol#L38).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, today I had an example of that:
In a NFT contract I wanted to create a mapping of metadata linked to addresses. So I tried it:

```
//create a mapping
mapping(string => address) public metadataUri;

//set a mapping
metadataUri[_uri] = _address;
```

But in that case, if I have one more address with the same string, the first one will override all next addresses with the same string. So in that case I should have something like this:

```
//create a mapping
mapping(string => mapping(address => uint)) public metadataUri;

//set a mapping
metadataUri[_stringURI][_address] = _uint;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes
The approval mechanisms in the token contracts use nested mappings.
The ERC1155 contracts use nested mappings to record the balances of an address.
Line number 24 at https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC1155/ERC1155.sol

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33549950)

Comment: Sorry if this is the incorrect format.
This link doesn't answer the question.
This is an example of what I wrote as the answer.
If the links become invalid then the person can directly search the mentioned contract.
Thank you